# How to populate tableview with dictionary key-values?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, key-value

I have a local JSON file called itemInfo.json which contains a single dictionary with close to 6000 key-value pairs consisting of an item name and an item id.

```
{ "itemName1" : 2564,
  "itemName2" : 470,
  "itemName3" : 1849,
  "itemName4" : 60,
  "itemName5" : 103 }
// continues for a few thousand more
```

I don't have a problem when it comes to loading the JSON file into the console but I don't know how to print out the item names onto tableview in a list. The ID's are not needed in the list as I just want to print the names.

```
public class DataLoader {

    @Published var userData: [String:Int] = [:]

    init() {
      load()
}

   func load() {
        
    if let fileLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "itemInfo", withExtension: "json") {

    do {

                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileLocation)

                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

                let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode([ String: Int].self, from: data)

                self.userData = dataFromJson

               } catch {

                print(error)

            }
        }
     }
 }
```

How do I populate tableview with all the item names in the tableViewController?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        
        cell.textLabel!.text = // not sure what goes here to populate list with names.

      
 return cell

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `userData` as array. Replace

```
@Published var userData: [String:Int] = [:]
```

with

```
@Published var userData: [String] = []
```

and assign the dictionary keys to the array

```
self.userData = Array(dataFromJson.keys)
```

In `cellForRow` display the item at given index

```
cell.textLabel!.text = userData[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went ahead and tried it and it says "No exact matches in call to initializer". I don't have an item struct but i'm not sure if it's needed. I tried also changing the decoder to jsonDecoder.decode([String].self, from: data) and it gave me "Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context".

Comment: Thank you so much! That seemed to do the trick! It makes sense now too haha Thanks!!